# Eureka Secured Discovery: Eureka client registers with Eureka Server with port 0

Tags: spring-boot, ssl, netflix-eureka, service-discovery

I have enabled ssl in Eureka Discovery Server, Config Server and other Eureka Clients. Config Server is able to register with Discovery server securely and the Eureka dashboard shows the correct health check URL information of Config Server. Config Server has a hard coded port, however, the other Eureka Clients have been configured to be assigned a random port. These clients are able to register with Eureka server, however, the port of these clients is shows as 0 on Eureka Dashboard. Not sure what am I missing here. Please take a look at the Yaml configuration below:

Eureka Server:

```
server:
   ssl:
      enabled: true
      key-store: classpath:nonprod.p12
      key-store-password: password
      key-store-type: PKCS12
      key-alias: dev-env-only
```

Config Server

```
server:
  port: 8888
  ssl:
     enabled: true
     key-store: classpath:nonprod.p12
     key-store-password: password
     key-store-type: PKCS12
     key-alias: dev-env-only

eureka:
  client:
    healthcheck:
      enabled: true
    register-with-eureka: true
    fetch-registry: true
  instance:
     secure-port-enabled: true
     non-secure-port-enabled: false
     status-page-url: https://${eureka.hostname}:${server.port}/actuator/info
     health-check-url: https://${eureka.hostname}:${server.port}/actuator/health
     home-page-url: https://${eureka.hostname}:${server.port}/eureka
```

Another Eureka Client

```
server: 
  port: 0
  ssl:
     enabled: true
     key-store: classpath:nonprod.p12
     key-store-password: password
     key-store-type: PKCS12
     key-alias: dev-env-only

    eureka:
      client:
        healthcheck:
          enabled: true
        register-with-eureka: true
        fetch-registry: true
      instance:
         secure-port-enabled: true
         non-secure-port-enabled: false
         status-page-url: https://${eureka.hostname}:${server.port}/actuator/info
         health-check-url: https://${eureka.hostname}:${server.port}/actuator/health
         home-page-url: https://${eureka.hostname}:${server.port}/eureka
```

I found some articles (Example https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/1843) which talks about updating properties of EurekaInstanceConfigBean by implementing a ApplicationListener for event WebServerInitializedEvent. The solution does not work either, because this event is trigger AFTER the Client has registered with Eureka Server.

```
private void updateHealthCheckUrls(WebServerInitializedEvent event) {

        EurekaInstanceConfigBean configBean = event.getApplicationContext().getBean(EurekaInstanceConfigBean.class);
        String hostname = configBean.getHostname();
        int port = configBean.getSecurePort();
        if (securePortEnable) {
            configBean.setHomePageUrl(HTTPS_PROTOCOL + hostname + COLON + port);
            configBean.setHealthCheckUrl(
                    HTTPS_PROTOCOL + hostname + COLON + port + configBean.getHealthCheckUrlPath());
            configBean.setStatusPageUrl(
                    HTTPS_PROTOCOL + hostname + COLON + port + configBean.getStatusPageUrlPath());
        }
    }
```

To play around further, I implemented a class similar to EurekaAutoServiceRegistration (made it primary bean) to override the implementation of **start** method to update EurekaInstanceConfigBean properties before calling serviceRegistry.register(this.registration);. It didn't worked either. Any help here would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Before a service registers with Eureka, we can implement a WebServerFactoryCustomizer in that service. this will ensure that a dynamic port is assigned to the service and the same port gets propagated to Eureka Server and Healthcheck endpoints

```
@Configuration
@Slf4j
public class CustomPortConfiguration implements WebServerFactoryCustomizer<ConfigurableServletWebServerFactory> {

    @Value("${port.number.min:1}")
    private Integer minPort;

    @Value("${port.number.max:65000}")
    private Integer maxPort;
    
    @Value("${server.port}")
    private String initialServerPort;

    @Override
    public void customize(ConfigurableServletWebServerFactory factory) {
        int port = SocketUtils.findAvailableTcpPort(minPort, maxPort);
        
        if(initialServerPort.equals("0")) {
            log.info("Port is 0, let's assign a dynamic port..");
            factory.setPort(port);
            System.getProperties().put("server.port", port);
        }
    }
}
```